# Footnote in reledmac environment

Tags: reledmac

After the last software update by means of TeX Live Utility, about a week ago, I had this strange problem that I cannot solve because I don't remember the updated packages so I don't know where exactely go to search.
The preamble of the MWE is the one that has always worked for both my current job as well for the previous ones.
The problem is related to footnotes in the reledmac environment and to highlight it I have set three types of notes:
1. normal footnote, which never causes the error.
2. familiar footnote and critical footnote, both causing it.

The problem manifests itself with a typesetting phase that never ends, a sort of loop.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{clipboard}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,positioning,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[]{pstricks}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[retainmissing]{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[strict=true,italian=quotes,maxlevel=2]{csquotes}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{adforn}
\setsecnumdepth{chapter}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{psvectorian}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\usepackage[series={A,B},noledgroup,noend]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\setgoalfraction{.98}
\setRlineflag{b}
\linespread{1}
\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{.49\textwidth}
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{.49\textwidth}
\columnsposition{C}
\AtEveryPend{\vspace{5pt}}
\AtBeginPairs{\sloppy}
\usepackage{polyglossia}    
\usepackage{babel}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{PT Serif}[Scale=1]
\selectfont
\setsansfont{Arial}[Scale=1]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{SBL Hebrew}[Scale=1]
\usepackage{bidi}


            \settypeblocksize{210.34mm}{135mm}{*}
            \setlrmargins{30mm}{*}{1.4142}
            \setulmargins{30mm}{*}{1.4142}
            \setheadfoot{5mm}{15mm}
            \setmarginnotes{2mm}{30mm}{1.5mm}
            \renewcommand*{\sidefootform}{}
            \checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
As any {dedicated}{{dedicato}} reader can clearly see, the Ideal of
 practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things
 in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be
 used as a canon for our understanding. As will easily be shown in the next section, reason would
 thereby be made to contradict, in view of these considerations, the
 Ideal of practical reason, yet the manifold depends on the phenomena.\footnote{normal footnote}



    \begin{pairs}
        \begin{Leftside} 
            \beginnumbering
                \pstart
The paralogisms of practical
 reason are what first give rise to the architectonic of practical
 reason. As will easily be shown in the next section, reason would
 thereby be made to contradict, in view of these considerations, the
 Ideal of practical reason, yet the manifold depends on the phenomena.%\footnoteA{familiar footnote}

 \edtext{prova}{\Afootnote[nosep]{critical footnote}}
 \pend

 \pstart
\begin{otherlanguage}{hebrew}
\texthebrew{אבג דהו זחט יכל מנס עפצ פרש ת}
\end{otherlanguage}
\pend

\pstart
 Hume tells us that the transcendental unity of
 apperception can not take account of the discipline of natural reason,
 by means of analytic unity. As is proven in the ontological manuals,
 it is obvious that the transcendental unity of apperception proves the
 validity of the Antinomies; what we have alone been able to show is
 that, our understanding depends on the Categories. It remains a
 mystery why the Ideal stands in need of reason. 
                \pend
            \endnumbering
        \end{Leftside}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \begin{Rightside} 
            \beginnumbering
                \pstart
Our concepts have lying before them the
 paralogisms of natural reason, but our a posteriori concepts have
 lying before them the practical employment of our experience. Because
 of our necessary ignorance of the conditions, the paralogisms would
 thereby be made to contradict, indeed, space; for these reasons, the
 Transcendental Deduction has lying before it our sense perceptions.
                \pend
                \pstart
Because of our necessary ignorance
 of the conditions, it must not be supposed that, then, formal logic
 (and what we have alone been able to show is that this is true) is a
 representation of the never-ending regress in the series of empirical
 conditions, but the discipline of pure reason, in so far as this
 expounds the contradictory rules of metaphysics, depends on the
 Antinomies. 
\pend

 \pstart
\begin{otherlanguage}{hebrew}
\texthebrew{אבג דהו זחט יכל מנס עפצ פרש ת}
\end{otherlanguage}
\pend

            \endnumbering
        \end{Rightside}
    \end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is caused by the new version of bidi. i am looking on.

Comment: I have openend and issue, as it is bidi responsability.

Comment: same problem with \sidefootnote but not with \ledinnernote and \marginpar

Comment: that is logical. I will try to solve an issue wenesday. In this delay, you can rolling back to older version of bidi using tlmgr.

Comment: It seems that I have to install the previous version of bidi?

Comment: no, you can up to the new version 34.8 of bidi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happens with version 34.4 of bidi package, which is loaded by polyglossia when using right-to-left language.

The author of bidi package changed bidi package code in order to solve this issue. And the version 34.8 of bidi package solves the problem.

Comment: @reviewers I think this a valid answer, please don't close. A package/class was not working and the maintainer fixed the problem and this answer tells us which version to use.

Comment: that provide an answer. The problem was created by one specific version of the package, and solved by an other one.